# Pod stuck in pending status

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                   ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  18m (x145 over 3h19m)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity, 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/controlplane: true}, that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

Please provide me a solution to deploy the pods on worker server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your pod is not getting scheduled to a Node. Can you try to run the below command ?

`kubectl taint nodes <name-node-master> node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule-`

To find the name of your node please use

`kubectl get nodes`